# RadioButton outer glow is cut off at start

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

This is my Radio group layout :

```
<RadioGroup
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/white"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                            android:text="Start" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                            android:text="End" />
                    </RadioGroup>
```

But when I touch and hold the first radio button. The glow effect has been cut off at left.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this by adding a startPadding to the `RadioGroup` or adding a startMargin to the `RadioButton`.

Comment: There's something weird about my app. paddingStart in RadioGroup works with other apps but my app doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Septimiu is correct : `startPadding` to the `RadioGroup` or adding a `startMargin` to the `RadioButton`

```
<RadioGroup
    ...
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    >
    ...
```

but I found a trouble appear with my activity : `android:hardwareAccelerated` is set to false in activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    ..
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    .. />
```

If set to this, paddingStart won't work. So I deleted it